# How to set the trust level for a ASP.NET Core API using Kestrel and IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Before ASP.NET core if I wanted to set the trust level for my application I would update my web.config to include:

```
<system.web>
  <securityPolicy>
    <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
  </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

In ASP.NET Core my app uses the new `dotnet publish` command to generate a web.config file based on this pretty standard Webhost configuration:

```
// Entry point for the application.
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

    host.Run();
 }
```

How can I update the trust level of my application in IIS using this code based approach? I have tried editing the web.config file directly but I keep breaking it and it doesn't *feel* like the right way of doing things...

Comment: trust level and CAS (Code Access Security) were deprecated and not supported for asp.net core https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2010/02/24/is-cas-dead-in-net-4/

Comment: also when CAS  was supported you could not change trust level to full from web.config if it were more restricted by machine.config, in web.config you could only set it to more restrictive than machine.config not less restrictive

Comment: Oh :( ok then. Yeah, I don't want full - I want more restrictive - minimal for example. Thanks for the link.

Comment: another link, http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/aspnet-partial-trust-applications